# Add/modify element for each object in array using jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

How can I add, or modify if the element already exists, an element for each object in an array using `jq`?

For example going from:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "Sophie",
        "lastname": "Haydock"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Toussaint",
        "lastname": "Louverture"
    }
]
```

to

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "Sophie",
        "lastname": "Haydock",
        "common": "something"
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Toussaint",
        "lastname": "Louverture",
        "common": "something"
    }
]
```

This is different from the question marked as duplicate in that it adds an element to an object in an array rather than add an object to an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do something with each element in an array, use `map`:

```
jq 'map(.common="something")'
```